# Laravel compound validation rule

Tags: laravel, validation

I would like to create a validation rule which checks if the combination of two values is unique.
There is a field for the street (id) and the house number. Both fields are required. Further, no new entry should be created if a certain combination of street and house number already exists.
How can I achieve this with Laravel?

What I have so far is only this:

```
protected $rules = [
    'street_id' => 'required',
    'tree_number' => 'required',
];
```

I guess this would be possible by using Rule Objects. Then I would query the DB if a certain combination is already stored. But can this be done in a simpler way as well?

Answer (score 0):

Something like below

```
'street_id' => ['required', 'unique:table,street_id,'.$request->input('street_id').',NULL,id,tree_number,'.$request->input('tree_number')]
```

Comment: And is it possible to integrate this in the rules-array as I have it or do I need to change it and put it into a function?